# Stuck with this code I have made

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords

This code should say "please enter a new password" if you enter a common password from the list I created, however it doesn't, it just says "Password Accepted" which it shouldn't. Can anyone help me please? Here is the code itself:

```
### Asks user for their name and password ###

print "Hello, what is your name?"

### Stores name in variable myName ###

myName = raw_input()

print "Nice to meet you "+myName+", please enter a password to continue."

common_passwords = [ '123456', 'password', '12345', '12345678', 'qwerty',
                     '1234567890', 'baseball', 'dragon', 'football', '1234567',
                     'monkey', 'letmein', 'abc123', '111111', 'mustang', 'access',
                     'shadow', 'master', 'michael', 'superman', '696969', '123123',
                     'batman', 'trustno1']

while True:
    password = raw_input()
    if len(password) < 8:
        print "Password is less than 8 characters."
        print "Your password has to be 8 characters or more."
        continue
    found = False
    for cpass in common_passwords:
        if cpass == password:
            print "You have selected a common password"
            print "Please choose a new password"
            found = True
            break
        if not found:
            print "Password Accepted"
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanted to do was probably :

```
for cpass in common_passwords:
        if cpass == password:
            print "You have selected a common password"
            print "Please choose a new password"
            found = True
            break  
if not found:
        print "Password Accepted"
```

Because you want to check if the entered password is found in `common_password`, and if it is not **after** your loop, the password is ok.

Besides, you can check for the presence of the password simply with :

```
If password in common_passwords:
        print "You have selected a common password"
        print "Please choose a new password"
else :
        print "Password Accepted"
```

Comment: Thanks, so it was my indentation all along, it works now, thanks a bunch. Had to do this for college and it's taken me 2 hours trying different things and all along it was the indentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a noob here but I'll be staying as didn't expect a response so quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `if password in common_passwords` which will test all common passwords in one go.
Your current error is that as you iterate through each one if the elements in commom_passwords if the 1st one isn't a match it will accept it.